# Overload resolution ambiguity... or not?

Tags: kotlin, overriding, method-reference, default-parameters

Here is some dull overloading:

```
class Dummy() {
    fun f(x: Unit) : String = "Disco"
    fun f(x: Unit, y: Unit = Unit) : String = "Mambo"
}
```

I'm not sure to understand why, but this works:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Dummy().f(Unit))           // Echoes “Disco”
}
```

However, that does not:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println((Dummy::f)(Dummy(), Unit)) // Fails: “Overload resolution ambiguity”
}
```

Any insight on the outcome difference?

Answer (score 4):

When you are calling `Dummy::f` there are two candidates with the same name **f**:

```
fun f(x: Unit) : String = "Disco"
fun f(x: Unit, y: Unit = Unit) : String = "Mambo"
```

The compiler does not know which one to take. This is because the function reference does not specify parameters, even if you change the signature of one of them to:

```
fun f(x: Int) : String = "Disco"
fun f(s: String) : String = "Mambo"
```

You will still have a problem because there is no way to infer the type with this statement: `Dummy::f`.

As a note, function references are used mostly to avoid lambda creations.

---

For example, if you have: <sub>(different names)</sub>

```
class Dummy() {
    fun f(x: Unit) : String = "Disco"
    fun g(x: Int) : String = "Mambo"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f = Dummy::f
    val g = Dummy::g
}
```

the type of `f` is `KFunction2<Dummy, Unit, String>`
and `g`type is `KFunction2<Dummy, Int, String>`

But if you define: <sub>(equal names)</sub>

```
class Dummy() {
    fun f(x: Unit) : String = "Disco"
    fun f(x: Int) : String = "Mambo"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f = Dummy::f
    val g = Dummy::f
}
```

You will have the “Overload resolution ambiguity” error because the compiler's information is too restricted to infer the correct function  from the two with the same name.

The problem is not the number of arguments, but using a function reference with many candidates.

Comment: Well, the very same candidates apply to the direct call to `f` (i.e. without using method referencing).

Comment: I see your point, resolving a method reference, s.a. `Dummy::f` is not the same as resolving a method call, s.a. `f(42)`. However, in this case, it is a “method reference call”:  `(Dummy::f)(42)` the reference is surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: I'm sorry I think you are limited by the language, you may fill a [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP) to solve this

Comment: Yes, but why complicate the language and the compiler to handle this case when just writing `Dummy().f(Unit)` would make the code more clear?

Answer (score 1):

If changing the function name is simple then just change it ,

if you are using a library or even primitive class like `String` you can create an extension as the following :

```
fun String.myToLowerCase(): String = this.toLowerCase()
fun Dummy.myF(): String = "Disco"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the name of one of the functions to resolve the ambiguous reference (eg because they are in a library), you can also create a simple function proxy.

This can even be made into an extension function:

```kotlin
// unchangeable overloaded functions
class Dummy() {
    fun f(x: Unit) : String = "Disco"
    fun f(x: Unit, y: Unit = Unit) : String = "Mambo"
}
```

```kotlin
//your code

fun Dummy.g(x:Unit, y:Unit = Unit) = f(x, y)

val functionF = Dummy::f //fine
val functionF2 = Dummy::g //fine
```